# WPFで透過WebP画像を正しく表示したい

Tags: .net, wpf

Windows10でWebPが表示できるようになりましたが、WPFで透過WebPを表示しようとすると透過している部分が壊れた表示になってしまいます。

正しく表示する方法はありますでしょうか。

[image: 表示が壊れた画像]

```xml
<Image Source="1_webp_a.webp"/>
```

画像は [WebP の Lossless and Alpha Gallery](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/gallery2) のものを使ってテストしています。

開発環境
- Windows10 Pro 64bit (1809)
- VisualStudio 2017
- .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: WPFではなく、商用のASP.NET向けですが、ここ [ASP.NET Image Resizer](https://www.gleamtech.com/imageultimate) からTrialでダウンロードできるサンプルで、表示する時の画像の縦または横のサイズを変更した場合に、上手く表示されていました。データのサイズと同じままで表示すると、質問と同じ状態になってました。ご参考に。

Comment: サイズ変更ということで、`BitmapImage`で`DecodePixelWidth`を指定して読み込んだらちゃんと透過しました。…これはバグっぽいですね。

Comment: この問題は[マイクロソフトに報告済み](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/1436)です

Answer (score 0):

質問時点ではWebPのライブラリがおそらく 1.0.2版で、表示時に画像ファイルの縦横サイズを変えずに表示すると、質問のように透過している部分が壊れた表示になっていました。
この時点でも、表示時に画像ファイルの縦横サイズを変更すると正常に表示出来ました。

@nee さんも確認されているように、おそらくバグであったと思われます。

現在のWebPのライブラリが 1.1.0版で、おそらく修正されていると思われますので、試してみてください。

WebPアーカイブ全体
[Index of downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp](https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/index.html)
1.0.2版系

```
libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x64-no-wic.zip     2019-01-19T07:59:14Z  4.4MiB
libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x64-no-wic.zip.asc 2019-01-19T07:59:13Z    833B
libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x64.zip            2019-01-19T07:59:14Z 3.55MiB
libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x64.zip.asc        2019-01-19T07:59:13Z    833B
libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x86-no-wic.zip     2019-01-19T07:59:14Z 3.77MiB
libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x86-no-wic.zip.asc 2019-01-19T07:59:13Z    833B
libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x86.zip            2019-01-19T07:59:14Z 3.01MiB
libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x86.zip.asc        2019-01-19T07:59:13Z    833B
```

1.1.0版系

```
libwebp-1.1.0-windows-x64-no-wic.zip     2020-01-06T23:53:55Z 4.77MiB
libwebp-1.1.0-windows-x64-no-wic.zip.asc 2020-01-06T23:53:53Z    833B
libwebp-1.1.0-windows-x64.zip            2020-01-06T23:53:55Z  3.6MiB
libwebp-1.1.0-windows-x64.zip.asc        2020-01-06T23:53:53Z    833B
```

確認に使ったサンプルプログラムの現在版
[ImageUltimate 30-day trial](https://www.gleamtech.com/imageultimate/try)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。直接libwebpを使えば大丈夫そうですね。ちなみに1.0.2のdwebp.exeを試してみたのですが正常に変換できました。ライブラリとして使うと問題あったのかな？

Comment: あるいは、質問時点で掲載されていたサンプル画像だけが問題だったのかもしれませんね。